How to avoid duplicate data on the table in PHP
I am currently testing this php code to insert the report data in the database but when I try to submit the report, i get some duplicate results as well
Here is my PHP code
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
    <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Room</th>
            <th>Devices</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Cause (If the status is broken)</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <?php
    $db_host = "localhost";
    $db_username = "root";
    $db_pass = "";
    $db_name = "umsdb";
    $conn = mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_username,$db_pass,$db_name)
    or die("Error, cannot connect to MySQL");
                            
    $sql= "SELECT * FROM user 
    INNER JOIN location ON user.lid=location.lid 
    INNER JOIN room ON location.lid=room.lid
    INNER JOIN devices ON room.rid=devices.rid;";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if($resultCheck > 0)
    {
             while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        { 
            $room = $row['ROOM_NAME'];
            $device = $row['DEVICE_NAME'];
                                
            echo "<tr>
            <td> " . $room . "</td>
            <td> " . $device . "</td>
            <td><select id ='status[]' name='status[]' size = '1'>
            <option>Select the status</option>
            <option value='Good'>Good</option>
            <option value='Broken'>Broken</option>
            </select>
            </td>
            <td><input type='text' class='form-control' name='cause'></td>
            </tr>";
            $prevRoom = false;
            $prevDevice = false;
            while (next ($row))
            {
                if($prevRoom == $room)
                {
                    //If subject name same as last, then empty value
                            // - or do whatever you want to do differently
                    break;
                    if($prevDevice = $device)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $prevDevice = $device;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                //somehow if the subject name is a duplicate echo it once and carry on with the other variables looping
                    $prevRoom = $room;
                    break;
                }
            }
                                    
                                    
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<tr rowspan='3'>No data filled</tr>";
    }
    ?>      
    </table>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn-primary"> 
    <?php
        $db_host = "localhost";
        $db_username = "root";
        $db_pass = "";
        $db_name = "umsdb";
        $conn = mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_username,$db_pass,$db_name) or die("Error, cannot connect to MySQL");
                            
        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
        $sql= "SELECT * FROM user 
        INNER JOIN location ON user.lid=location.lid 
        INNER JOIN room ON location.lid=room.lid
        INNER JOIN devices ON room.rid=devices.rid;";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if($resultCheck > 0)
        {
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
            { 
                $uid = $row['uid'];
                $did = $row['did'];

                $status = $_POST['status'];
                foreach($status as $condition)
                {
                    $cause = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['cause']);
                    $date = date("Y/m/d");
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO report (uid,did,R_STATUS,CAUSE,R_DATE)
                    VALUES ('$uid','$did','$condition','$cause','$date');";
                    if(mysqli_multi_query($conn, $sql))
                    {
                        echo "Adding Successfully!";
                        header("Location:home.php");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
                    }
                                            
                }   
            }
        }
        else
        {
        echo "No data found";
        }

                                
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
    ?>                      
    </form>

This is the report.php. I hope everyone can understand this code because it's been a while i didn't make this code very complex
My output for that php code after submitting report has become like this



Devices
Status
Cause




Smart TV
Good
Broken Screen


Smart TV
Broken
Broken Screen


Portable Audio
Good
Broken Screen


Portable Audio
Broken
Broken Screen



My expected output after submitting should be like this



Devices
Status
Cause




Smart TV
Broken
Broken Screen


Portable Audio
Good





Run the query with DISTINCT. It returns only the distinct result set.

I think this is more a MySQL question than a PHP question. You have a query that joins four tables with inner joins and returns more rows than you need. DISTINCT definitely won't cut it. I would suggest to remove the PHP, ask the question about the query itself, and tag it as such. Note that people here might ask you for input data and schemas.

Sorry because this is my first time asking question.

No need to be sorry. Asking good question here is actually quite difficult. Tagging a question correctly, adding all the information needed, and showing the minimal code needed to reproduce the problem, will help getting an answer.

Your current POST handling iterates all rows, and for each row iterates all statuses with no association between the room/device and statuses. You should remove the non-unique ids and add device id as the index for the status array <select name='status[$did]' size = '1'>. Then when iterating over the received post request foreach($_POST['status'] as $device_id => $condition) and check that $condition has a value. Why are you initialising your db connection twice? What are your $prevRoom and $prevDevice checks supposed to do? It is definitely not doing what you think it is.

Your main select query does not make sense. Consider 10 users with lid = 1, 10 rooms with lid = 1 and each room has only 2 devices. That's 200 rows for only 20 devices. What is the purpose of including users in this query, especially as they are not displayed in your table? You are also returning all columns but only using ROOM_NAME and DEVICE_NAME.

I provide two ways to avoid this problem:
Method 1: Create a joint unique index in MySQL
Method 2: Before inserting, check whether the content to be inserted already exists. If it exists, do not insert it. Otherwise, insert it.

Don't give any suggestion here @shiwei.du.. This is only for solution section. If you want to give any suggestion put that in comment section , like me... Please update solution or delete this post
